# How to Customize ListView Column Headers

Tags: vb.net, listview, columnheader

I am fairly new to programming and I have never attempted writing my own class before.  I would like to try.  What I am trying to achieve is to write my own (basic) listview control to start with.  I am struggling with the first bit...

As a start I want to try and centre all of the Column Headers but keep the row text using their own formatting.  I would like to implement a custom property if possible, but to start with I just want to override the DrawColumnHeader event.

Can someone point me in the right direction (maybe an example).  I have setup a new class, inherited the listview control and added the following event:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawColumnHeader(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs)
```

However, I am finding that any code I place in this event isn't getting fired when the listview gets drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason was that I didn't have the OwnerDraw property set to True.